Tests in parallel execution failing due to Thread safety error
I am trying to run Selenium Webdriver tests in parallel on a single machine, using TestNG. I have 2 @Test methods, where 2 different users log in to the same application and reach the home page. I need @Test methods to run in parallel, and write to an ExtentReports report.
My problem is, Two user detail is fetched and Two browser instance is launching but only one user details is entering in one instance and other instance is failing with below error
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Thread safety error; this instance of WebDriver was constructed on thread TestNG-test=JuryApp_Parallel_exceution-1 (id 18) and is being accessed by thread TestNG-test=JuryApp_Parallel_exceution-2 (id 19)This is not permitted and will cause undefined behavior
My code for login is writen as below
`public class LoginWithMapping_Parallel {
private static  ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
private ThreadLocal<ExcelGeneric> excelReader = new ThreadLocal<>();
private ThreadLocal<LoginPage> loginPage = new ThreadLocal<>();
private ThreadLocal<JavascriptExecutor> js = new ThreadLocal<>();
private ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait> wait = new ThreadLocal<>();
private ThreadLocal<String[]> userCredentials = new ThreadLocal<>(); 
private static AtomicInteger userCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);


@BeforeMethod
@Parameters({ "browser","sheetName" })
    public synchronized void setupBrowserAndLogin(@Optional("Chrome") String browser,
            @Optional("LoginData") String sheetName) throws InterruptedException { try {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver.set((new ChromeDriver()));
    excelReader.set(new ExcelGeneric(ElementRepository.testDataExcelPath));
    ef = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), ElementRepository.class);
    wait.set(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(60)));
        } 
    }

    public  synchronized void openBrowser(String webUrl) 
    {
        driver.get().manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get().get(webUrl);
    }

    public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public ExcelGeneric getExcelReader() {
        return excelReader.get();
    }
    
    public WebDriverWait getWait() {
        return wait.get();
    }
    
    public ExtentTest getlogger()
    {
        return logger.get();
    }


    public synchronized String[] getUserCredentials()
    {
        return userCredentials.get();
    }

public String[] getUserCredentials() {
    return userCredentials.get();
}

public  void logintoapplication() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        CommonMethods.spinner(getDriver(), "//div[@class='spin-large']");
        getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ef.externalEmail));
        ef.externalEmail.sendKeys(credentials[0] + "@accenture.com");
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Username entered");
        getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ef.nextBtn));
        ef.nextBtn.click();
        getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ef.mailPassword));
        ef.mailPassword.click();
        ef.mailPassword.sendKeys(credentials[2]);
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Password Entered");
        getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ef.signnBtn));
        ef.signnBtn.click();
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Clicked On Submit Button");
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Login Successful");
        
    } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

`
**test cases are written in different class : **
public class JuryApp_Parallel_exceution extends LoginWithMapping_Parallel {
    @Test(dataProvider = "Event_Creation", dataProviderClass = ReadExcel.class)
    public void EventCreation(String Url, String eventType, String eventName, String displayName,String eventFormat, String scaleFlag, String scaleRange,String startDate, String endDate, String closeDate) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            // Start the test logging with ThreadLocal ExtentTest
            logger.set(rpt.startTest("Creating an Event", "Creating an Event")
                    .assignCategory("EventCreation_JuryApp"));

            openBrowser(Url);  // Calls the getLoginPage from parent class
                logintoapplication(ElementRepository.ideaSubmitter, ElementRepository.sheetName_TestUser);  // Login

            New_JuryApp newjuryapp = new New_JuryApp(driver.get());
            newjuryapp.addEvent(logger.get(), eventType, eventName, displayName, eventFormat, 
                                scaleFlag, scaleRange, startDate, endDate, closeDate);

            logger.get().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Event created successfully");

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            logger.get().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Error in Event Creation: " + e.toString());
            Assert.fail("Testcase failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "JuryDetails", dataProviderClass = ReadExcel.class)
    public void categoryCreation(String Url, String eventType, String eventName) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            // Start the test logging with ThreadLocal ExtentTest
            logger.set(rpt.startTest("Adding category to an Event", "Category")
                    .assignCategory("Category_JuryApp"));

            openBrowser(Url);  // Calls the getLoginPage from parent class
            logintoapplication(ElementRepository.mentor, ElementRepository.sheetName_TestUser);  // Login

            New_JuryApp newjuryapp = new New_JuryApp(driver.get());
            newjuryapp.addCategory(logger.get(), eventType, eventName);

            logger.get().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Category added successfully");

        } catch (AssertionError | Exception e) {
            logger.get().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Error in Category Creation: " + e.toString());
            Assert.fail("Testcase failed", e);
        }
    }

}

At first both the user details was entering to same instance then used "ThreadGuard.protect" to set browser , issue is resolved but now both the test cases are launching browser but only one user details is entering in one instance and other is failing
please help me resolving thread safety error
